# How to URL-encode HTML-escaped text in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a string `Picture > 1000 words`, it is stored HTML-escaped `Picture &gt; 1000 words`. I need to URL encode the original string to get `Picture%20%3E%201000%20words`

I tried different sequences of filters, but none of them produces the desired result.

```
{# title = "Picture &gt; 1000 words" #}

{{ title | url_encode(true)  }}
{{ title | raw | url_encode(true)  }}
{{ title | url_encode(true) | raw  }}
```

The result is the same in all 3 cases: `Picture%20%26gt%3B%201000%20words`. How to avoid Twig to encode already escaped text and get the desired outcome?

Comment: `;` is the required end of an html_entity so it should be `&gt;`

Comment: @Baldrs tx. mistyped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get this `Picture%20%3E%201000%20words` you should have raw string without html entities

So this should work:

```
{% set title = "Picture > 1000 words" %}

{{ title | url_encode(true)  }}
```

If you really need to decode entities inside a template, you can register a custom filter for that purpose:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('decode_entities', function ($string) {
   return html_entity_decode($string);
});

// then connect it with environment

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

And then use it like that:

```
{{ title | decode_entities | url_encode(true) }}
```

**EDIT**

Just tried your example with latest upstream twig, and this works as you expect:

```
{{ title | raw | url_encode(true) }}
```

Your problem is incorrect string entities

Comment: Thanks You! Your custom filter suggestion worked for me. Will try to update Twig to see if `raw` also works.

Comment: twig insisted on encoding html entities when using `url_encode`, even with `raw`, so I ended up creating my own filter